# can a webservice encapsulate an assembly or a shared object on each call?

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

We haven an asmx web service, made in visual studio, implanted in an IIS server.

The case is that the webservice's project is in a solution with another project (library class project), and some of the functions of the webservice use a reference to that project. That library class project has a shared object that is used internally. I mean; webservice function -> library class function -> shared object.

The issue is that the shared object is, obviously, shared among all the webservice calls...  I need, if that's possible, that each time the webservice function is called, the whole library class assembly has its own context within that call. I'm experience an undesired behaviour with concurrent calls because all are using, of course, the same instance of the shared object. Is there a way to configure the assembly, the project or the IIS to achieve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "We haven an asmx web service, made in visual studio, implanted in an IIS server." - Implantd???? - WOW!!!!

Comment: No! you don't have to use shared object. `MSDN: Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.`

Comment: Hi TS, thank you for your answer, and sorry for my english. The issue is not about being thread safe. The DLL the webservice uses came from a project with 140 classes. All of them uses the shared component. How could I access that component from all the classes without it being shared and without having to have each class receiving or instantiating that object?

Comment: Yes - **It is** about **thread safety**. Do you understand **shared** ?? If you have `public static class...` - you can have as many threads accessing it as you wish. Now, if you have `public class X....  public void DoThis()`, and if later you create instance for each - you most likely thread safe. But if somewhere you have `var globalX = new X()`, and all your components call `globalX` there could be suspicion - it is  NOT thread safe. And BTW - this is not an answer. This is just a comment. You need to post some code to get the answer